# How can I calculate the sum of values of Plaid API transaction array in Java Script?

Tags: javascript, plaid

Apologies for the potentially silly question - I'm fairly new to coding/JavaScript.

I am using [Plaid's](https://plaid.com/) sandbox environment to pull in transactional data in a sandbox environment. Right now, I define the following as transactionData:

```
    let transactionsData = [];
transactions.forEach(function(account) {
  account.transactions.forEach(function(transaction) {
    transactionsData.push({
      account: account.accountName,
      date: transaction.date,
      category: transaction.category[0],
      name: transaction.name,
      amount: transaction.amount
    });
  });
});
```

I can successfully render the individual transactions row by row in a [material table](https://material-table.com) like so:

```
    const transactionsColumns = [
  { title: "Account", field: "account" },
  { title: "Date", field: "date", type: "date", defaultSort: "desc" },
  { title: "Name", field: "name" },
  { title: "Amount", field: "amount", type: "numeric" },
  { title: "Category", field: "category" }
];

          <MaterialTable
            columns={transactionsColumns}
            data={transactionsData}
            }}
```

I know this has to be super simple, but all I want to do is sum the transactionsData and render that single summed value elsewhere on my page. If I write transactionsData.length I can receive the count of the transactions quite easily. I have tried the following somewhat similar syntax but have not found it to work:

```
array.reduce(function(total, currentValue, currentIndex, arr), initialValue)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you can provide some dummy data, I'll create a snippet that you can run to verify the code in my answer.

Comment: Hey Tex - Really appreciate your help. Thank you. Sorry for the unclean output- i'm having trouble exporting the array- but here is a few sample transactions just for your awareness (all dummy data).
Citi 12/31/2019 United Airlines 500 Travel
Huntington Bank 12/31/2019 United Airlines 500 Travel
Navy Federal Credit Union 12/31/2019 United Airlines 500 Travel
Citi 12/29/2019 Uber 072515 SF**POOL** 6.33 Travel
Huntington Bank 12/29/2019 Uber 072515 SF**POOL** 6.33 Travel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's total, using [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const transformed = [{"account":"Navy Federal Credit Union","date":"2020-01-01","category":"Travel","name":"United Airlines","amount":500},{"account":"Navy Federal Credit Union","date":"2019-12-30","category":"Travel","name":"Uber 072515 SF**POOL**","amount":6.33},{"account":"Navy Federal Credit Union","date":"2019-12-27","category":"Food and Drink","name":"Tectra Inc","amount":500}]

const unrounded = transformed.reduce(
  (acc, { amount }) => acc + amount,
  0
);

const roundCents = amount => Math.round(amount * 100) / 100;

const total = roundCents(unrounded);

console.log(total);
```

A plainer version of the above, with no destructuring:

```js
const transformed = [{"account":"Navy Federal Credit Union","date":"2020-01-01","category":"Travel","name":"United Airlines","amount":500},{"account":"Navy Federal Credit Union","date":"2019-12-30","category":"Travel","name":"Uber 072515 SF**POOL**","amount":6.33},{"account":"Navy Federal Credit Union","date":"2019-12-27","category":"Food and Drink","name":"Tectra Inc","amount":500}]

const unrounded = transformed.reduce(
  (acc, transaction) => acc + transaction.amount,
  0
);

const roundCents = amount => Math.round(amount * 100) / 100;

const total = roundCents(unrounded);

console.log(total);
```

And here's how to transform `transactionsData` with [`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), rather than `forEach`:

```js
const transactionsData = [{ accountName: 'a1', transactions: [{ date: '2020', category: ['c1'], name: 'n1', amount: 100 }, { date: '2020', category: ['c2'], name: 'n2', amount: 100 }]}, { accountName: 'a2', transactions: [{ date: '2020', category: ['c3'], name: 'n3', amount: 100 }, { date: '2020', category: ['c4'], name: 'n4', amount: 100 }]}]

const transformed = transactionsData.flatMap(({ accountName, transactions }) =>
  transactions.map(({ date, category, name, amount }) => ({
      account: accountName,
      date,
      category: category[0],
      name,
      amount
    })
  )
);

console.log(transformed)
```

And again, a plainer version, without the destructuring:

```js
const transactionsData = [{ accountName: 'a1', transactions: [{ date: '2020', category: ['c1'], name: 'n1', amount: 100 }, { date: '2020', category: ['c2'], name: 'n2', amount: 100 }]}, { accountName: 'a2', transactions: [{ date: '2020', category: ['c3'], name: 'n3', amount: 100 }, { date: '2020', category: ['c4'], name: 'n4', amount: 100 }]}]

const transformed = transactionsData.flatMap(account =>
  account.transactions.map(transaction => ({
      account: account.accountName,
      date: transaction.date,
      category: transaction.category[0],
      name: transaction.name,
      amount: transaction.amount
    })
  )
);

console.log(transformed)
```

`Array.prototype.map` is the correct method to use if you want to create a new array from an existing one, and `Array.prototype.flatMap` is the correct method to use if you need a flattened array and `map` would generate a nested one.

Comment: Hi Tex - thanks so much for this thorough answer. I have another likely silly question for you: whenever i define "transformed" (exactly as you do in your last codeblock above) I get this error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot?

Comment: @wharfchillin I've converted the last two code samples to runnable snippets by adding dummy transaction data that seems to match what you'd get from Plaid. The code in both examples ran the first time without requiring changes, so it was valid, at least given my understanding of the input data. It's difficult to translate the data you added in your previous comment, but if you can add actual data (`console.log(JSON.stringify(transactionsData))` may help), I'll update the snippets with your 'actual' dummy data.

Comment: Hi Tex, here's a sample of the output (all dummy data).

`[{"account":"Navy Federal Credit Union","date":"2020-01-01","category":"Travel","name":"United Airlines","amount":500},{"account":"Navy Federal Credit Union","date":"2019-12-30","category":"Travel","name":"Uber 072515 SF**POOL**","amount":6.33},{"account":"Navy Federal Credit Union","date":"2019-12-27","category":"Food and Drink","name":"Tectra Inc","amount":500}]`

Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: I need the input data so I can see how it differs from my expectations.

Comment: Sorry I may have misspoke when I said output data, I ran the console `(console.log(JSON.stringify(transactionsData))` you sent and this was what the first few lines of the result was. Are you referring to something different when you say input data? Thanks for bearing with my ignorance lol. 

But to tie back to my original post, I pretty much just want to take this array and sum the `"amount:" field` for every transaction and return the total.

Comment: Ok, the data you posted in your comment is already in the correct shape to be pasted into either of my first two snippets. I went ahead and did that for you, and everything worked fine, with the minor exception of a [floating point number rounding](https://floating-point-gui.de/errors/rounding/) issue, which I also addressed in both snippets. Let me know if you have any other questions.